# Pandas: .apply with multi index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a big dataframe as input that looks like this:

```
index type price1 price2
3000   C    300   600
3000   P    500   500
3500   C    300   400
3500   P    400   200
4500   P    100   350
```

I would like to do some calculation to get the min of fw1 base on a diff and the max of fw2.
Right now I do the following but it takes a couple of seconds:

```py
# Create DataFrame
data = {'type': ['C', 'P', 'C', 'P', 'C', 'C'],
        'price1': [6., 4., 3., 2., 5., 6.],
        'price2': [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[3000.,
                               3000.,
                               3500.,
                               3500.,
                               4000.,
                               5000.])

k_c = np.unique(df.index[(df['type'] == 'C')])
k_p = np.unique(df.index[(df['type'] == 'P')])

common_k = np.intersect1d(k_c, k_p)

fw1 = np.array([k + df['price1'].values[(df['type'] == 'C') & (df.index == k)] / 2
                - df['price2'].values[(df['type'] == 'P') & (df.index == k)] / 2
                for k in common_k])

fw2 = np.array([k + df['price2'].values[(df['type'] == 'C') & (df.index == k)] / 2
                - df['price1'].values[(df['type'] == 'P') & (df.index == k)] / 2
                for k in common_k])

max_fw = max(fw1)
min_fw = min(fw2)
```

I try to use a pivot then .apply but impossible to make it work with a multi index. The resulting pivot looks good but I can't find a way to calculate max(fw1) min(fw2) with the .apply

```py
fwd_fast = (
    df.reset_index()
        .pivot(index='index', columns='type', values=['price1', 'price2'])
        .dropna()
)
#not working
fwd_fast.apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series([row.index + row[('C', 'price1')] / 2 - row[('P', 'price2')] / 2], index=['fw1']),
    axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
out=fwd_fast.apply(
    lambda row: pd.Series([row.name + row[('price1','C')] / 2 - row[('price2','P')] / 2], index=['fw1']),
    axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

**Explaination:**

In your code there are 2 key errors i.e:

you are using
`('C', 'price1')` and `('P', 'price2')` instead of `('price1','C')` and `('price2','P')`

You are wrongly accessing value of index by `row.index` instead of `row.name`

**Note:** you can also reduce the cost of `apply()` method by simply doing:

```
out=(fwd_fast.index+fwd_fast[('price1','C')]/2-fwd_fast[('price2','P')] / 2).to_frame('fw1')
```

output of `out`:

```
        fw1
index   
3000.0  3002.0
3500.0  3499.5
```